# when import tensorflow is pressed it shows the following errors

Tags: tensorflow

when import tensorflow  is pressed it shows the following errors i have the version 1.5.0 of tensorflow and i installed it through "python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl" bcz ntg other command worked to install tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\riya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems


for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: hi reena, welcome to SO. Can you please add details like version, installation method etc?

Comment: C:\Users\riya>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\riya\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: six, numpy, wheel, absl-py, protobuf, tensorflow-tensorboard
Required-by:

Comment: can you do `pi install protobuf==3.6.0` and try again?

Comment: no, it's not working. It shows the same error

Comment: I tried this and there indeed seems to be a problem with the wheel file. Can you try `pip install tensorflow==1.5.0`? First uninstall using `pip uninstall tensorflow`

Comment: if i try pip install tensorflow==1.5.0 it shows the following error i tried it earlier also ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5.0

Comment: where are you running this command?

Comment: command prompt in windows i was using python 3.8 version then i changed it too 3.5 even then it shows the same error

Comment: It works thankyou after changing python version from 32 bit to 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import tensorflow` issue has been resolved by changing python from `32` bit to `64` bit and python version must be 3.5-3.7 because 3.8 is not compatible for installing tensorflow through `pip install tensorflow==1.5.0`.